# Blob trigger- Issue with processing a zip file which is structured like folder.zip>folder>(170 files-gifs, png, txt etc)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-code, zip

I have an azure function app which is a blob trigger. It detects new zip files in a blob container and extracts them to a new container. 
It works perfectly for zip files which are structured like file.zip>(170 items like gifs, pngs, txt, html) but it cannot process the zip files structured like file.zip>file>(170 items like gifs, pngs, txt). 
Should I use a different library or is there an issue with the code?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

namespace IV4.Function
{
    public static class iv4Unzipthis
    {
        [FunctionName("Unziptestiv4")]
        public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("input-files/{name}", Connection = "unzip_STORAGE")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");

            string destinationStorage = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("destinationStorage");
            string destinationContainer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("destinationContainer");

            try{
                if(name.Split('.').Last().ToLower() == "zip"){

                    ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(myBlob);

                    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(destinationStorage);
                    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(destinationContainer);

                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                    {
                        log.LogInformation($"Now processing {entry.FullName}");

                        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(entry.Name);
                        using (var fileStream = entry.Open())
                        {
                           await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                log.LogInformation($"Error! Something went wrong: {ex.Message}");

            }            
        }
    }
}
```

I takes just 1 file item of those 170 and throws an error for other items in the folder. here is the log stream for the execution-

2019-04-01T14:14:54.814 [Information] C# Blob trigger function Processed blob

Name:Scan_Report.zip

Size: 407942 Bytes

2019-04-01T14:14:54.858 [Information] Now processing Scan_Report/index.html

2019-04-01T14:14:54.928 [Information] Now processing Scan_Report/

2019-04-01T14:14:54.928 [Information] Error! Something went wrong: The argument must not be empty string.

Parameter name: blobName

2019-04-01T14:14:54.929 [Information] Executed 'Unziptestiv4' (Succeeded, Id=8fa15f91-928c-4010-93b1-4da9af43bbc3)

Comment: If the answer works, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When use  `file.zip>file>(170 items like gifs, pngs, txt)`, there will be an path without file name like `"file.zip/file/"` and it causes the error(The other correct ones like `file.zip/file/11.txt`).

Please try the code below and works fine at my side, just add `if (entry.FullName.EndsWith("/")) { continue; }` in the `foreach()` code, like below:

```
                    //your other code

                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                    {
                        // add this line of code.
                        if (entry.FullName.EndsWith("/")) { continue; }

                        log.LogInformation($"Now processing {entry.FullName}");

                        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(entry.Name);
                        using (var fileStream = entry.Open())
                        {
                            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
                        }
                    }
```